# Object automatic create new with old every time when load / save game.?

Tags: c#, unity

My problem with this DontDestroyOnLoad(cube.gameObject); When I load my player position its create new object with default and saved position respectively. I have a screen shot for better understand.

First scene without save 
[image]

Second scene with save game.

[image]

Here is my code.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

public static float speed;
//public static Player control;
public float moveSpeed = 10f;
public float turnSpeed = 50f;
public Transform cube;
public float x, y, z,x1 ,y1, z1;
public int s;

//public static List<Game> savedGames = new List<Game>();
public static Player Instance;
// Use this for initialization

// Update is called once per frame

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {

    if(other.tag == "Player1"){
        DontDestroyOnLoad(cube.gameObject);
        //DontDestroyOnLoad (other.gameObject);
    }
}

void Awake ()
{       

    if (Instance == null) {
        DontDestroyOnLoad (this.gameObject);

    } else {
        DestroyObject(gameObject);
    }
}

public void Start () {
    speed = 50f;    
}

//Update is called once per frame
public void Update () {

    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        transform.Translate(-Vector3.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, -turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    }       

public  void Save(){

    //Player.savedGames.Add ();
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter ();
    FileStream fs = File.Create ("D:/playerinfo3.txt");

    playerData pd = new playerData ();
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("currentscenesave",SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);

    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("cubeposx",cube.position.x);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("cubeposy",cube.position.y);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("cubeposz",cube.position.z);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("cuberotx",cube.eulerAngles.x);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("cuberoty",cube.eulerAngles.y);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("cuberotz",cube.eulerAngles.z);


    pd.x = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("cubeposx");
    pd.y = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("cubeposy");
    pd.z = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("cubeposz");
    pd.x1 = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("cuberotx");
    pd.y1 = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("cuberoty");
    pd.z1 = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("cuberotz");
    pd.s = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("currentscenesave");

    SceneManager.LoadScene (pd.s);
    bf.Serialize (fs,pd);
    fs.Close ();



}


  public void Load(){
    //transform.position = new Vector3 (PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("cubeposx"), PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("cubeposy"), PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("cubeposz"));
    if(File.Exists("D:/playerinfo3.txt"))
    {

        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter ();
        FileStream fs = File.Open ("D:/playerinfo3.txt",FileMode.Open);
        playerData pd = (playerData)bf.Deserialize (fs);
        pd.x  = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("cubeposx");
        pd.y = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("cubeposy");
        pd.z = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("cubeposz");
        pd.x1 = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("cuberotx");
        pd.y1 = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("cuberoty");
        pd.z1 = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("cuberotz");
        fs.Close ();
        SceneManager.LoadScene (PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("currentscenesave"));
        cube.position = new Vector3 (pd.x,pd.y,pd.z);
        cube.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (pd.x1,pd.y1,pd.z1);

        Debug.Log ("currentscenesave"+ " "+ pd.s);
        Debug.Log ("currentscenesave"+ " "+ pd.x);
        Debug.Log ("currentscenesave"+ " "+ pd.y);
        Debug.Log ("currentscenesave"+ " "+ pd.z);
    }



  }

  [Serializable]
  class playerData{

    public float x, y, z;
    public float x1, y1, z1;
    public int s;

 }



}
```

Comment: The obvious solution would be to simply not use `DontDestroyOnLoad` on anything you want to reset when loading a savegame. Do you have a good reason why you have it? Note that since Unity5 [you can load and unload scenes additively](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.html) (add a scene without leaving the previous one) which solves many situations where you would otherwise have to use `DontDestroyOnLoad`.

Comment: without `DontDestroyOnLoad` I am not able to load player position. @Philipp

Comment: And also without `DontDistroyOnLoad` I can not get my player to next scene after trigger new scene @Philipp

Comment: You said that i can load and unload scene additively. can you post example code.pls or link of tutorial @Philipp

Comment: I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by using the ability of the SceneManager to load scenes additively.

Create one base-scene with everything which is supposed to be present in every level (like the player-character, for example). Nothing in this scene requires `DontDestroyOnLoad`.

Create every level as a separate scene. Those scenes should not contain anything from the base-scene.

When you switch to another level (savegame, level select, game progression or otherwise), first unload the previous level (if loaded) with [`UnloadScene(currentLevel)`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.UnloadScene.html). Then load the new level with [`SceneManager.LoadScene(newLevel, LoadSceneMode.Additive)`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html).

`LoadSceneMode.Additive` loads the scene without destroying anything in the previous scene. When you then unload a scene which was previously loaded this way, anything which originates from a different scene stays intact. This allows you to switch out your levels without losing anything from the base-scene.

Comment: This work fine. But i am unable to unload scene. `void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
  
  OnLevelWasLoaded (level:2);

 }

 void OnLevelWasLoaded(int level) {
  if (level == 2)
   //print("Woohoo")
   SceneManager.UnloadScene(2);
  SceneManager.LoadScene (4,LoadSceneMode.Additive);
 }` This is my code.

Comment: I manage it. destroy object of old scene and problem solve. thanx